# How to interpret multi-class deep learning classifier by using SHAP?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, shap

I trained a multi-class classifier in Keras on IRIS data set. I want to interpret my deep learning model by using [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap). I use the following lines of code where model is my trained neural network classifier, `X1[train]` is my training input, and `X1[test]` is my test input:

```
import shap
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, X1[train])
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X1[test])
```

However, I get this error (I am fine when my **softmax** has one output in binary classification. The problem appears when softmax has *more than 1 output*):

```
ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Layer sequential_96 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input:
```

How can I solve this problem and get SHAP values for a single class in multi class deep learning classifier?

Answer (score 1):

How are you importing keras? When doing `from keras import...` I had the same issue, but changing to `from tensorflow.keras import ...` the DeepExplainer worked